# Spectrum of a differential operator on $L^2(0, \infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $A:H^n(0, \infty) \subset L^2(0, \infty) \to L^2(0, \infty)$ be the differential operator defined by
$$Af:= \sum_{j=0}^na_j f^{(j)}$$
for all $f \in H^n(0, \infty),$ where $a_j \in \mathbb{C}$ and $a_n \neq 0$. I need to show that $$\sigma(A)= \{ P(iz) : \mbox{Im}(z) \geq 0\}$$
if $P(z):= a_0 + a_1z+\cdots+a_nz^n$. I have shown that  $S:=\{ P(iz) : \mbox{Im}(z) \geq 0\} \subseteq \sigma(A)$ and that if $\lambda \notin S$ then $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}: R(A-\lambda I) \subseteq L^2(0, \infty) \to L^2(0, \infty)$ is a bounded operator and $R(A-\lambda I)$ is closed, but I am struggling to show that $R(A-\lambda I)=L^2(0, \infty)$ if $\lambda \notin S$.

Thanks for any help.